# Loading and removing datasets using paste in R

Tags: r, paste

I have a large number of similarly named .R datasets. I am trying to load them in (which i can do successfully), do something to them and then remove them from the workspace all in one loop. I am struggling however to remove them because they are in the wrong class coming out of the paste command. While I know whats wrong, I have no idea how to correct my code, so suggestions are welcome. Here is some example code

```
for(i in 1:n){
    load(paste("C",i,".R",sep=""))
    # do stuff to dataset
    rm(paste("C",i,sep="")) #this line is clearly wrong
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `list` argument of `rm` should do what you want. It takes `character` of variable names which are removed. So, something like this should work:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  loaded <- load(paste0("C", i, ".R"))
  # do stuff to dataset
  rm(list = loaded)
}
```

Note, that the `load` function returns a `character` with the names of the loaded object(s). So we can use that when removing the loaded object(s) again. The loaded object(s) with `load` does not nessesarily correspond to the filename.

Comment: Cheers. This does what I need to do, although for my actual code (rather than example) I used the line
   rm(list=paste("C",i,".1",sep=""))

Comment: @VinnyDavies Great, glad I could help. I guess I just assumed too much. Welcome to SO. (Remember to mark the question as answered *if* you think it is)